# Java Client Refusing to connect to Remote Server

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am very New with Hbase, its really different from  RDBMS. I developed a simple application and trying to configure it to remote server 162.18.17.55. I am getting connection refusing error. I am unable to to forward to check where it went wrong, when i type zk_dump in Putty , then i got the respective server details, I can login into putty and tables into database, but when i use java client i am not able to connect to server. please can any one guide me this process and issue

Comment: can you post your core-site.xml ? HadoopMaster is probably set somewhere... Do you have it in your host file ? The host information transfered by zookeeper is not known by your client application

Comment: My core-site.xml file                                 <configuration>
<property>
 <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
 <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
 </property>
<property> <name>fs.default.name</name>
 <value>hdfs://HadoopMaster:54310</value>
 </property>
</configuration>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are connecting to `Zookeeper` it returns `HadoopMaster` as host instead of the ip address since you put `HadoopMaster` in your `core-site.xml` file. Now you need to add `HadoopMaster` in your `/etc/hosts` file to be able to recognize the host address. Add this line to your host file

```
162.18.17.55      HadoopMaster
```

Comment: In etc/hosts i have 162.18.17.55   HadoopMaster and 162.18.17.56 HadoopNode

Comment: In my etc/hosts I have these configuration list         '#127.0.0.1      localhost
#127.0.1.1      HadoopMaster

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

# /etc/hosts (for master AND slave)
162.18.17.55   HadoopMaster 
162.18.17.56   hadoopnode **'

Comment: this value "127.0.1.1 HadoopMaster" is already precede with the "#" sign in your host file ?

Comment: there's also some known problems with hadoop and IPv6 you might consider disabling IPv6 for hadoop by adding the following line to your conf/hadoop-env.sh : 

exportHADOOP_OPTS=Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true